# Regarding memory size of android application

Tags: android, android-memory

Hei,   I had developed an android application by using phone-gap framework. The memory size of .apk file is 350 kb. After installation, the usage of memory by the application is 2.00 mb. I want to reduce the usage of memory after installation,actually that is the requirement. On surfing Google, I worked on Images and images are of required pixels only. Is there any alternative to reduce the memory size of application .... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project may have files that were compressed while generating apk file for you. These files are decompressed when you install the application.

Try to reduce the size of the files in your source code.